# Method not found without being fully qualified, using statement does not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a class "Extensions" that is defined in `namespace Backend` and is `static class Extensions`.

In it there is a method `public static string MakePath(params string[] paths)`. I usually use the class for extension methods but this one isn't such.

Yet if I were to call it from another class like so `MakePath("asd", "asd")` I get a "does not exist in the current context" error without the option to add a "using" statement.

Fully qualifying it, like so `Extensions.MakePath` fixes that but I'd prefer a using directive. Putting `using Backend;` at the top of the file does nothing. Visual Studio simply does not associate it like it should. Never had such a problem before.

How can I fix this so that Visual Studio would know "MakePaths" is in the class "Extensions" in the namespace "Backend" and a "using" directive would be detected, so that I can use the method, without fully qualifying it?

Comment: Note that calling the class "extensions" is misleading. An extension method is a very [specific thing in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

Comment: _using static Backend.Extensions;_ See [using directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive)

Comment: @DavidG, well, it's full of extension methods, so... :D

Comment: Not really though, they're just methods. An extension method would extend a class, and would have a `this` parameter.

Comment: Just making sure... You're aware of `Path.Combine`, right?

Comment: @DavidG ...yeah, that's exactly the kind of methods that class is full of.

Comment: @canton7, yes, but in my experience it has NEVER been useful or worked right. This method correctly concatenates strings with ending backslashes.

Comment: @J.Doe .NET Core 2.1 and .NET Standard 2.1 introduced [`Path.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.join?view=netcore-3.1) to fix that complaint

Comment: @canton7 thanks, didn't know about that one! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve it by the following directive `using static Backend.Extensions` and call your method like `MakePath("asd", "asd");`, without class name. [`using static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static) was introduced in C# 6.0

Comment: Huh, thanks! Is it because it's a static class that makes `using` different and creates this problem?

Comment: @J.Doe I think, that initial cause of your issue is that you have another `Extensions` class or namespace (more likely) in your solution, it's hard to tell without context. But `using static` is helpful, when you want (or need) to call a static method without specifying a class name

Comment: @J.Doe Before `using static`, you were *never* able to invoke a static method from a different class without using the class name, or an instance method from another class without invoking it on an instance